# How to customize system sounds

Tags: sound, 13.10, tweak

Yesterday I've found a [web page](http://www.trekcore.com/audio/) containing all the iconic sounds/noises from all the star trek series/films. Being the nerd that I am, I thought it would be fun to change some of the system sounds into star trek sounds.

Like when I get an error message the sound "TNG Red Alert 1" plays, or when transferring a file it plays "TNG Transporter 4".

While I am a big star trek nerd, I'm still quite new to Linux/Ubuntu. So My question is if anyone knows how to to this or knows a tool that might help.

Im using Ubuntu 13.10 With default Unity.

Thank you in advance, Ahead warp factor one!

Answer (score 1):

You can find all the sounds in the folder:

```
/usr/share/sounds
```

if you rename your sound to the one you want to replace. (I think only ogg and wav are allowed so you may need to convert your sound files).

Comment: Isn't there a way to add your own sounds? I mean without replacing the stock ones. I'm trying to add more files, no effect, seems weird that this can only be hacked.